# Relay circuit not working

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, breadboard, nodemcu

I have connected my relay with a nodeMCU so that when I give commands to relay through nodeMCU the led connected to relay gets powered up. But after proper connection also it doesn't power up.

[image: My setup]

Comment: Where is your schematic?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the other power connection

you've got the relay board GND connection hooked up, but it need a VCC connection too.

Comment: I powered the relay using a breadboard power supply module (a black wire connected from breadboard power supply to vcc point in relay board)

Comment: Oh, I thought that was a shadow!

Comment: but there's no circuit to the breadboard power supply, connect the ground to that supply also.